# How do I squash my last N commits together?

Tags: git, rebase, squash, git-squash

How do I squash my last N commits together into one commit?

Comment: Related: [Git - combining multiple commits before pushing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6934752/456814).

Comment: For squashing upto THE first commit see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one/9254257#9254257

Comment: post squash one need to do force push http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge

Comment: In addition to the posted answers, GUI clients can do this easily. I can squash dozens of commits in GitKraken with only four clicks.

Comment: All answers i tried messed up submodules. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236694/how-do-i-squash-all-commits-without-losing-submodules) didn't.

Comment: Why is there no command like `git fold --from abc --to efg`?

Answer (score 2966, accepted):

Use `git rebase -i <after-this-commit>` and replace "pick" on the second and subsequent commits with "squash" or "fixup", as described in [the manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode).

In this example, `<after-this-commit>` is either the SHA1 hash or the relative location from the HEAD of the current branch from which commits are analyzed for the rebase command. For example, if the user wishes to view 5 commits from the current HEAD in the past the command is `git rebase -i HEAD~5`.

Comment: What is meant by `<after-this-commit>`?

Comment: `<after-this-commit>` is commit X+1 i.e. parent of the oldest commit you want to squash.

Comment: If you've already pushed the commits, you will need to push -f to forcibly move the remote branch to your new commit. This will upset anyone who was working on top of the old commits, though.

Comment: I personally found this article (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) a lot easier to follow than the one linked (same site).

Comment: The difference between this `rebase -i` approach and `reset --soft` is, `rebase -i`allows me to retain the commit author, while `reset --soft` allows me to recommit.

Sometimes i need to squash commits of pull requests yet maintaining the author information. Sometimes i need to reset soft on my own commits.

Upvotes to both great answers anyways.

Comment: I always end up screwing up the rebase for some reason, reset --soft seems more intuitive for most purposes.

Comment: `Use git rebase -i <after-this-commit> and replace "pick" on the second and subsequent commits with "squash" or "fixup", as described in the manual.`
uhhhh... wut?

Comment: is there a way to squash using git rebase without using interactive mode?

Comment: @Cheeso, [this article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history#git-rebase-i) helps explain the `squash` and `fixup` designations used during an interactive rebase.  Specifically, the `squash` and `fixup` designations tell Git how to combine the commit messages.

Comment: The explanation for `<after-this-commit>` is needlessly complicated. With a simpler explanation (the chosen words are almost self-explanatory, already, but the *given* explanation overcomplicates), this answer would be perfect.

Comment: It should be `<after-and-including-this-commit>`

Comment: I feel like you really mean `<before-this-commit>`, but you describe such an argument as a commit in the past.

Comment: Here is a practical example: https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/combining-multiple-commits-into-one/

Comment: What you supposed to do after the squashing to get it pushed?

Comment: @Geynen Thanks, that link provide the **only** description that made full sense. Now I can even tell people that `<after-this-commit>`, means exactly that. It is **non-inclusive** and will let you *pick* and *squash* commits after that one, as long as none of them are an initial commit. If you want to include initial commit, you need to use the `git reset` method instead.

Comment: Note that you can re-order commits when rebasing interactively - e.g. if you made commits A, B, then C, you can squash commit C onto A by swapping the order of the lines of B and C when prompted (and changing C to "squash").  Useful if you have committed more work since the commit you are trying to squash.

Comment: `git reset --soft $(git merge-base HEAD master) && git commit --reuse-message=HEAD@{1}`

Comment: But shouldn't it be **For example, if the user wishes to view 5 commits from the current HEAD in the past the command is `git rebase -i HEAD~6`.** instead?

Comment: What if there are too many `pick`to replace manually?

Comment: After rebase, if we want to push to remote, we need to use `--force` flag to push. If we don't use, `push` will fail.

`
git push --force <remote> <remote_branch>
`

Comment: And you can quit the editor by pressing ```ESC```and typing ```:wq!```

Answer (score 5621):

You can do this fairly easily without `git rebase` or `git merge --squash`. In this example, we'll squash the last 3 commits.

If you want to write the new commit message from scratch, this suffices:

```bash
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git commit
```

If you want to start editing the new commit message with a concatenation of the existing commit messages (i.e. similar to what a pick/squash/squash/…/squash `git rebase -i` instruction list would start you with), then you need to extract those messages and pass them to `git commit`:

```bash
git reset --soft HEAD~3 && 
git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
```

Both of those methods squash the last three commits into a single new commit in the same way. The soft reset just re-points HEAD to the last commit that you do not want to squash. Neither the index nor the working tree are touched by the soft reset, leaving the index in the desired state for your new commit (i.e. it already has all the changes from the commits that you are about to “throw away”).

#### Edit Based on Comments

You have rewritten that history you must than use the --force flag to push this branch back to remote. This is what the force flag is meant for, but you can be extra careful, and always fully define your target.

```bash
git push --force-with-lease origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: Ha! I like this method.  It is the one closes to the spirit of the problem.  It's a pity that it requires so much voodoo.  Something like this should be added to one of the basic commands.  Possibly `git rebase --squash-recent`, or even `git commit --amend-many`.

Comment: When doing the soft reset, what's the best way to auto-determine the target commit id, i.e. of the last pushed commit? I don't want to have to lookup and count `3`, for example.

Comment: @A-B-B: If your branch has an “upstream” set, then you may be able to use `branch@{upstream}` (or just `@{upstream}` for the current branch; in both cases, the last part can be abbreviated to `@{u}`; see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)). This may differ from *your* “last pushed commit” (e.g. if someone else pushed something that built atop your most recent push and then you fetched that), but seems like it might be close to what you want.

Comment: I like this solution in general but like providing my own commit message.  [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275508/is-there-a-way-to-squash-a-number-of-commits-non-interactively/24018435#24018435) is a solution that sets up an alias so that you can do **git squash 3 'my commit message'**

Comment: This kinda-sorta required me to `push -f` but otherwise it was lovely, thanks.

Comment: Here's an alias in case you'd like to fixup instead of squash: `fixup = "!f() { base=${1:-2}; git reset --soft HEAD~$base && git commit -C ORIG_HEAD~$(expr $base - 1); }; f"`.

Comment: `git log --one-line` or something like that will display a list of commit IDs and messages, one per line.  Very useful with this solution.

Comment: @2rs2ts git push -f sound dangerous. Take care to only squash local commits. Never touch pushed commits!

Comment: after doing this while trying to push getting error error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:....'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind. I found how to solve this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667884/how-to-squash-commits-in-git-after-they-have-been-pushed

Comment: I also need to use `git push --force` afterwards so that it takes the commit

Comment: Make sure your working copy has no other changes (`git stash` them or something). Otherwise, you have the chance to commit them into the squashed commit too, which might be not something you intend to do.

Comment: I want to upvote this, but I can't bring myself to be the one who changes the upvoted count from `1337`...

Comment: This helped me when ```git rebase --interactive``` was giving me ```error: could not apply```. Possibly because one of the commits I was trying to squash was a merge with a resolved conflict.

Comment: the git reset --soft HEAD~3 definitely is better in terms of number of conflicts to solve. 
our test case was HEAD~6, but one of the commit was a merge commit, so we had 45 commits and the rebase -i HEAD~6 gave us so many conflicts which end up failing the build. And when we used reset --soft it gave us 0 conflicts to solve.

Comment: `git push -f` doesn't appear to alter the commit log of the upsteam repository.

Comment: I put this into `~/bin/git-funge` as a script because we have to have single commit messages on pull requests. Now I just write `git funge HEAD~3` and edit my messages to suite a single PR message and save and it is all sorted. :) Thanks for a great answer. (funge is my way of meaning fungible but reads better as a verb :P)

Comment: I think better than those saying to force push is to just make a new feature branch.  So something like ```git checkout -b feature-name-squashed```, follow these directions, then push the new squashed version of the branch.  If you do this, you will have access to the full commit logs of the feature (on feature-name) if you ever need them.

Comment: Having to `git push -f` is always a requirement after rewriting history.  It CAN be bad to rewrite history, certainly if you are doing it to a shared repository.  But that's a separate subject not related to this answer (which is great).

Comment: If you have already pushed the commits that you are squashing and you want to avoid having to do a force push, create a new branch at the commit you are at and push it:
git checkout -b new-branch-name && git push -u

Comment: I thik this is currently the best method. But watch our for its caveat: If you have unstaged or uncommitted changes, Git won't stop you from performing these operations, and your uncommitted changes will get merged into the squashed commit. This probably is or is not what you want.

Comment: A noteworthy difference between this approach and "real" rebase is that the authors of the original commits are lost here.

Comment: Not sure what version this was added in but you can use this one liner to reliably reuse the latest commit message and author: `git reset --soft {base-commit} && git commit --reuse=HEAD@{1}`

Comment: Try to get used to `git push --force-with-lease` instead of `git push -f` !

Comment: Don't forget `+` if your other commits were already pushed to remote - i.e. `git push origin +name-of-branch`

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala I've not tried it yet, but EthanB added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21890252/836169) below, based on this one, to do something like that using `.gitconfig`.

Comment: I accidentally did `git reset --soft HEAD~3` twice. Be aware that they stack.

Comment: For those curious about `HEAD..HEAD@{1}`, `r1..r2` specifies a range of commits that are reachable from `r2` excluding those that are reachable from `r1`, and `<refname>@{<n>}` specifies the n-th prior value of that ref.  So here, `HEAD..HEAD@{1}` means all the commits between the current `HEAD` and where `HEAD` was right before the reset.

Comment: If you want to target a commit specifically you can do so by providing the hash, but it wasn't as simple as replacing the index with the hash. I got this by using Source Tree: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks reset -q --soft <Your SHA here>
git commit   The hash that should be provided though should be the commit just before your target.

Comment: If my current branch has branched off 'otherbranch', and I want to squash everything I did on the current branch before I merge it into 'otherbranch', I can do `git reset --soft otherbranch` rather than having to work out how many commits ago that was

Comment: This worked for me where the `git rebase -i` did not. I was trying to squash some work that had a couple of merge commits thrown in the middle and I kept running in to conflicts (I didn't think that was possible, but I'm guessing it was because of the merge commits that were removed). Tried this and voila! No complaints, worked first time. Highly recommended. :)

Comment: Put this in your bashrc for an alias to squash the last two commits together, using the message of the first commit --> alias gsquash="git reset --soft HEAD~2 && git commit --edit -m\"$(git log --format=%B HEAD@{0}..HEAD@{2})\""  # Squash last two commits together, using message of first commit.

Comment: Leaving this here in case it helps someone.  Using bash, I just define a function `squash() { git reset --soft HEAD~$1; git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"; }` and then I can just say `squash 2` or `squash 3`.

Comment: @MatthiasM re "git push -f sound dangerous. Take care to only squash local commits. Never touch pushed commits!"
Depends on your workflow and context.  Using GitHub it is normal (actually required) to have to `git push -f` after a rebase of a branch.  This may be no different.  If you're working on your own branch for a PR, there's no problem.  Also, you cannot force-push to a protected branch (like `main` on GitHub).  So there's no danger if your project is set up right.

Comment: What if code push has already been done and I want to remove previous commits from history. Will it work?

Comment: you'll end up losing information and history if files were moved around. You should use the correct approach mentioned from @user1376350

Comment: I regret upvoting this because it put my repo into a strange state that misbehaves under my normal (very simple) workflow. `git pull`, `git push`, now I have N+2 commits instead of N. The log looked normal so as a novice, this feels like a booby trap.

Comment: And you can quit the editor by pressing ```ESC```and typing ```:wq!```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this about `-f`: _"and always fully define your target"_.

Answer (score 1006):

You can use `git merge --squash` for this, which is slightly more elegant than `git rebase -i`.  Suppose you're on master and you want to squash the last 12 commits into one.

WARNING: First make sure you commit your work—check that `git status` is clean (since `git reset --hard` will throw away staged and unstaged changes)

Then:

```bash
# Reset the current branch to the commit just before the last 12:
git reset --hard HEAD~12

# HEAD@{1} is where the branch was just before the previous command.
# This command sets the state of the index to be as it would just
# after a merge from that commit:
git merge --squash HEAD@{1}

# Commit those squashed changes.  The commit message will be helpfully
# prepopulated with the commit messages of all the squashed commits:
git commit
```

The [documentation for `git merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) describes the `--squash` option in more detail.

---

*Update:* the only real advantage of this method over the simpler `git reset --soft HEAD~12 && git commit` suggested by Chris Johnsen in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-can-i-squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/5201642#5201642) is that you get the commit message prepopulated with every commit message that you're squashing.

Comment: @Mark Amery: There are various reasons that I said that this is more elegant.  For example, it doesn't involve unnecessarily spawning an editor and then searching and replacing for a string in the "to-do" file.  Using `git merge --squash` is also easier to use in a script.  Essentially, the reasoning was that you don't need the "interactivity" of `git rebase -i` at all for this.

Comment: Even though I appreciate the advantage of having a verbose commit message for big changes such as this, there's also a real *disadvantage* of this method over Chris's: doing a **hard** reset (`git reset --hard`) touches a lot more files. If you're using Unity3D, for instance, you'll appreciate less files being touched.

Comment: Another advantage is that `git merge --squash` is less likely to produce merge conflicts in the face of moves/deletes/renames compared to rebasing, especially if you're merging from a local branch. (disclaimer: based on only one experience, correct me if this isn't true in the general case!)

Comment: I'm always very reluctant when it comes to hard resets - I'd use a temporal tag instead of `HEAD@{1}` just to be on the safe side e.g. when your workflow is interrupted for an hour by a power outage etc.

Comment: @PaulDraper well let's say due to a power outage or other interruption you cannot finish this, and next time you're in that machine out of habit you do a `git pull`, obtaining a few commits but not the ones you wanted to squash. I don't know if there also is a `HEAD@{2}` etc but with a temporary tag you don't have to remember... of course so long as you don't `git gc --prune` you can still retrieve your HEAD, but it's just more tedious

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, you may be interested in `git reflog`. Git already "tags" recent commits for this purpose. `git gc --prune` shouldn't change that, unless you ask to expire the reflog entries. It may all be a matter of preference.

Comment: @PaulDraper Thanks for the info, yeah it's probably preference - and Python's ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Wonderful.. this destroyed my commit. -1

Comment: @B T: Destroyed your commit? :( I'm not sure what you mean by that. Anything that you committed you'll easily be able to get back to from git's reflog. If you had uncommitted work, but the files were staged, you should still be able to get their contents back, [although that will be more work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7376959/223092). If your work wasn't even staged, however, I'm afraid there's little that can be done; that's why the answer says up-front: "First check that git status is clean (since git reset --hard will throw away staged and unstaged changes)".

Comment: maybe is outdated? I did the reset --hard and when doing the merge --squash I get this error "fatal: You cannot combine --squash with --no-ff."

Comment: FYI: If you do `git merge --squash HEAD@{1}` and get a `error: unknown switch 'c` back you are probably running in powershell console. Probably easiest way to continue is to temporarily move to ordinary command shell through `cmd` then do your `git merge --squash HEAD@{1}` and then go back to powershell through leaving the command shell by `exit`. (I haven't bothered to figure out how to run the `git merge --squash HEAD@{1}` through powershell.)

Comment: I would also argue that "elegant" is not the right word to use here. I would say it's slightly quicker rather than slightly more elegant since you don't spawn an editor. It's a great advantage but a hard reset also seems dangerous since you could easily lose your data.

Comment: @LosManos I just found that we can use the command in powershell.
git merge --squash 'HEAD@{1}'
just put HEAD@{1} inside ' ' to make it work.

Comment: I get "Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by .. commits, and can be fast-forwarded". I then do commit or pull or merge (--ff-only) and get the same commit history as before..

Comment: How can I create a zsh function out of it with this line `git merge --squash HEAD@{1}` which results in a parse error.

Comment: For those who use SourceTree, I normally do all the steps described here in cmd line until 'git merge --squash HEAD@{1}' (inclusive). Then I refresh SourceTree with F5 and perform my commit via SourceTree to benefit from the ui when editing the commit message.

Answer (score 373):

**2020 Simple** solution without rebase :

```bash
git reset --soft HEAD~2 
git commit -m "new commit message"
git push -f
```

2 means the last two commits will be squashed. You can replace it by any number

Comment: This solution shouldn't be encouraged.  Using the`-f   (force)` option in `push` is a dangerous practice, particularly if you're pushing to a shared repo (i.e public history) that'll make life dfficult for contributors

Comment: works good for the personal feature branches, should not be used on the branches where multiple people work, but I'd say latter may be in some cases just bad organization.

Comment: if the goal is to add this new commit to master as part of an ongoing pr, you could use `git reset --soft $(git merge-base feature master)` and then `git commit`.

Comment: @FXQuantTrader when you `git rebase -i` you have to force-push too, don't you? Unless you're not using `--force-with-lease` I don't think there's any harm in that solution.

Comment: @FXQuantTrader: If everybody force-pushes, the opposite the case. Almost always there is need to push with `--force`. Doing this aligns you well with the rest of the team and different remote locations as you know what is going on. Also you know which part of the history has stabilized already. No need to hide that.

Comment: I would argue that pushing with `force` should be actually _encouraged_ with very well communicated impacts of this approach –– Force-pushing goes hand in hand with rebase and synchronization of work so it is better, in my humble opinion, that more people know about the effects of this action, rather than being an exoteric command that people are scared to use.

Comment: Agree with Matheus, force pushing to feature branches is fine and should be encouraged with rebasing. Pushing directly to main should always be restricted anyways.

Comment: @blisher  Use rebase in your local repo to your hearts content. But once you push to a "shared" public branch (main, master, develop) it's just bad to be rewriting shared branch commit histories.

Comment: It sucks that this answer gets 20 times less votes than the top answer, when the major difference is that this answer *warns you* about needing to `push -f` and that one doesn't.

Comment: @FXQuantTrader: Force is required here, or you'll get an error when pushing.

Comment: This one should be the accepted one.

Comment: This is absolutely the simplest solution I've seen so far. Thank you!

Comment: `--force` is bad. Prefer `--force-with-lease` ;·)

Comment: best Solution for commit message change

Comment: This is not the best answer. This approach replaces all your commit messages with the new one. Using interactive rebase, you can combine existing messages in whichever way that makes sense for you via an editor. There's less chance you might forget to mention something important.

Comment: I see complaints about --force, but don't people realize that even rebase solution requires to force push (unless the commits that are being squashed have not been pushed yet)?

Even here, if commits have not been pushed yet, I suppose --force is not required, right?

Comment: I cannot count the number of times I referenced this answer. I wish I could +1 you for each visit. Thank you.

Answer (score 320):

I recommend avoiding `git reset` when possible -- especially for Git-novices.  Unless you really need to automate a process based on a *number* of commits, there is a less exotic way...

1. Put the to-be-squashed commits on a working branch (if they aren't already) -- use gitk for this
2. Check out the target branch (e.g. 'master')
3. `git merge --squash (working branch name)`
4. `git commit`

The commit message will be prepopulated based on the squash.

Comment: This is the safest method : no reset soft / hard (!!), or reflog used !

Comment: It would be great if you expanded on (1).

Comment: @Adam: Basically, this means use the GUI interface of `gitk` to label the line of code that you are squashing and also label the base upon which to squash to.  In the normal case, both of these labels will already exist, so step (1) can be skipped.

Comment: Note that this method doesn't mark the working branch as being fully merged, so removing it requires forcing deletion. :(

Comment: For (1), I've found `git branch your-feature && git reset --hard HEAD~N` the most convenient way. However, it does involve git reset again, which this answer tried to avoid.

Comment: @Kyrstellaine: Yes, the merge does not affect the working branch -- so you will have to remove it manually, if you want it removed (an optional step 5).

Comment: @Adam:  There is an assumption in this answer that you already have a working branch that has diverged from your target branch, and that you want to squash all the commits on the working branch from the divergence point from target, and apply them to the target branch in a single squash (non-merge) commit.   If your changes are already committed on the target branch, this answer doesn't help, since if you follow it, it will just add a new commit to your target on top of the ones you want to squash (in that case, you'd need to rebase to rewrite history on the target branch to remove commits).

Comment: Futher elaboration regarding (1): If you are adept with `gitk` (a GUI tool), then you can (with care) move and rename branches.  For example, you can place a new branch called `tobesquashed` on the same commit with `master`, then delete `master` and recreate it at the base of the to-be-squashed commits. ... Then proceed with step 2.

Comment: Easy. This is the best answer.

Comment: @BrentBradburn, would you provide an real-world example, I did not understand your answer.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin, [gitk](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Graphical-Interfaces) is a GUI for viewing your Git repository.  I highly recommend using gitk or something similar.  Exploring your repository with a graphical tool should help bring this into focus.

Using gitk, you can attach the head of branches (such as 'master' and 'my_new_branch') to specific commits in the history.  Once this is done, the steps 2, 3, and 4 are trivial.  See my previous "Further elaboration" comment for more...

Comment: I agree that this is the safest way, and also as a note to Git-novices, if it's your first time using this command you can also create duplicate branches of the target and working branch to get a feel for the command first before actually applying it to the real branches.

Comment: Important to note that method assumes the working branch being squash will be deleted afterwards, because if you add more changes to it and then do a regular `git merge` it will bring merge all of the previous commits that were squashed

Comment: The idea is to create a helper branch that is at head of master(latest commit) and goes down until the end of the squashed commit(1).Checkout master(2). Git merge --squash (3) How does git know to merge the helper branch and master? git commit(4) git branch -D helper (5)

Answer (score 320):

Thanks to [this handy blog post](https://www.devroom.io/2011/07/05/git-squash-your-latests-commits-into-one/) I found that you can use this command to squash the last 3 commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This is handy as it works even when you are on a local branch with no tracking information/remote repo.

The command will open the interactive rebase editor which then allows you to reorder, squash, reword, etc as per normal.

---

**Using the interactive rebase editor:**

See [the Git docs on using the interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_changing_multiple).  A summary follows:

From the example above, the interactive rebase editor shows the last three commits.  This constraint was determined by `HEAD~3` when running the command `git rebase -i HEAD~3`.

The commits are listed in reverse order to what you may expect.  The oldest commit is displayed on line 1, and the newest commit on the last line.  The lines starting with a `#` are comments/documentation.

The documentation displayed is pretty clear.  On any given line you can change the command from `pick` to a command of your choice.

I prefer to use the command `fixup` as this "squashes" the commit's changes into the commit on the line above and discards the commit's message.

As the commit on line 1 is `HEAD`, in most cases you would leave this as `pick`.
You cannot use `squash` or `fixup` as there is no other commit to squash the commit into.

You may also change the order of the commits. This allows you to squash or fixup commits that are not adjacent chronologically.

[image: interactive rebase editor]

---

**A practical everyday example**

I've recently committed a new feature.  Since then, I have committed two bug fixes.  But now I have discovered a bug (or maybe just a spelling error) in the new feature I committed.  How annoying!  I don't want a new commit polluting my commit history!

The first thing I do is fix the mistake and make a new commit with the comment `squash this into my new feature!`.

I then run `git log` or `gitk` and get the commit SHA of the new feature (in this case `1ff9460`).

Next, I bring up the interactive rebase editor with `git rebase -i 1ff9460~`.  The `~` after the commit SHA tells the editor to include that commit in the editor.

Next, I move the commit containing the fix (`fe7f1e0`) to underneath the feature commit, and change `pick` to `fixup`.

When closing the editor, the fix will get squashed into the feature commit and my commit history will look nice and clean!

This works well when all the commits are local, but if you try to change any commits already pushed to the remote you can really cause problems for other devs that have checked out the same branch!

[image]

Comment: do you have to pick the top one and squash the rest? You should edit your answer to explain how to use the interactive rebase editor in more detail

Comment: Yes, leave `pick` in line 1. If you choose `squash` or `fixup` for the commit on line 1, git will show a message saying "error: cannot 'fixup' without a previous commit".  Then it will give you the option to fix it: "You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'." or you can just abort and start over: "Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.".

Comment: I am constantly using this command. I recommend to add an alias for that called `gr3`:
`alias gr3='git rebase -i  HEAD~3'`

Comment: More on the git rebase -interactive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704829/1705829)

Comment: Git rebase -i .. turns the git commits around: the newest is the last in the list and the oldest the first.Am I looking wrong?

Comment: @Timo, correct.  Oldest at the top, newest at the bottom.  That's why you need to `pick` the first line.  And when you choose `squash` or `fixup` on a line, it will put the changes into the commit on the line above.

Comment: This feels like the best answer when you know that you want to squash a certain amount of commits or at least see the commits you can squash by entering some arbitrary number. Generally, I use this .

Comment: @Staghouse yeah, it gives you a lot of control and it’s super flexible. You might want to squash a commit which fixes a type in a variable name but also reword a commit message at the same time

Comment: I don't think the 1st line contains the latest commit by default

Comment: @Andy It should do because of `HEAD~3` <- 3 commits starting at head

Comment: I think you have to check this once again, e.g create a branch and chech-in three commits with messages like 1,2,3 respectively and then run git -i head~3
If I do this, I get this:
pick 541da752 1
pick f281aba6 2
pick f4a7341d 3


where the last line is the most recent commit

Comment: @Andy Thanks! I've updated the answer, and also included a link to [the relevant Git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_changing_multiple).

Answer (score 161):

Based on [Chris Johnsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/1580288),

Add a global "squash" alias from bash: (or Git Bash on Windows)

```bash
git config --global alias.squash '!f(){ git reset --soft HEAD~${1} && git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"; };f'
```

... or using Windows' Command Prompt:

```bash
git config --global alias.squash "!f(){ git reset --soft HEAD~${1} && git commit --edit -m\"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})\"; };f"
```

Your `~/.gitconfig` should now contain this alias:

```
[alias]
    squash = "!f(){ git reset --soft HEAD~${1} && git commit --edit -m\"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})\"; };f"
```

Usage:

```
git squash N
```

... Which automatically squashes together the last `N` commits, inclusive.

Note: The resultant commit message is a combination of all the squashed commits, in order. If you are unhappy with that, you can always `git commit --amend` to modify it manually. (Or, edit the alias to match your tastes.)

Comment: Interesting, but I'd much rather type the squashed commit message myself, as a descriptive summary of my multiple commits, than have it auto-entered for me. So I'd rather specify `git squash -m "New summary."` and have `N` determined automatically as the number of unpushed commits.

Comment: @A-B-B, This sounds like a separate question. (I don't think it's exactly what the OP was asking; I've never felt a need for it in my git squash workflow.)

Comment: This is pretty sweet. Personally I'd like a version that uses the commit message from the first of the squashed-together commits. Would be good for things like whitespace tweaks.

Comment: @funroll Agreed. Just dropping the last commit msg is a super common need for me. We should be able to devise that...

Comment: @SteveClay Somewhere around here: `git commit --edit -m\"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})\"` :)

Comment: you might like to count to the branch or commit with something like `git rev-list @{1}..head --count`

Comment: I was hoping the following would work, it doesn't quite: `f(){c=$(git rev-list ${1}..head --count); git reset --soft HEAD~$c && git commit --edit -m\"$(git log --format=%B --reverse ${1}..head)\"; }`

Comment: is there a way to squash all the commits for that branch instead of last X commits?

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy What would that even mean? All commits to branch X, since it diverged from branch Y? You'd still need to enter the name of branch Y. For me, it's simpler to just count the number of commits.

Comment: @EthanB yes, merging with the branch ancestor (at the time of initial branching) is quite useful. The problem is we cannot rely on the ancestor's name because it could be changed. Right now the best way is to look at git-log, count and use the marvelous `squash` alias of yours.

Comment: @A-B-B you can use `git commit --amend` to further change the message, but this alias lets you have a good start on what should be in the commit message.

Comment: @dashesy Thanks for the (unintentional) reminder that folks might not be familiar with `--amend`. I've updated the answer to provide the hint.

Answer (score 94):

In the branch you would like to combine the commits on, run:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~(n number of commits back to review)
```

example:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

This will open the text editor and you must switch the 'pick' in front of each commit with 'squash' if you would like these commits to be merged together. From documentation:

## p, pick  = use commit

## s, squash  = use commit, but meld into previous commit

For example, if you are looking to merge all the commits into one, the 'pick' is the first commit you made and all future ones (placed below the first) should be set to 'squash'. If using vim, use **:x** in insert mode to save and exit the editor.

Then to continue the rebase:

```
git add .

git rebase --continue
```

For more on this and other ways to rewrite your commit history see [this helpful post](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: Please also explain what the `--continue` and vim `:x` does.

Comment: The rebase will happen in blocks as it goes through the commits on your branch, after you ```git add``` the correct configuration in your files you use ```git rebase --continue``` to move to the next commit and start to merge.  ```:x``` is one command that will save the changes of the file when using vim see [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Saving_a_file)

Answer (score 90):

To do this you can use following git command.

```
 git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

n(=4 here) is the number of last commit. Then you got following options,

```
pick 01d1124 Message....
pick 6340aaa Message....
pick ebfd367 Message....
pick 30e0ccb Message....
```

Update like below `pick` one commit and `squash` the others into the most recent,

```
p 01d1124 Message....
s 6340aaa Message....
s ebfd367 Message....
s 30e0ccb Message....
```

For details click on the [**Link**](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)

Comment: More details on SO on the git rebase -interactive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704829/1705829)

Answer (score 82):

Here is another visual example of what would follow after executing:
`git rebase -i HEAD~3`

[image: Here there is a visual example of what would follow after executing git rebase for the three last commits]

Source: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-squash/

Answer (score 66):

If you use TortoiseGit, you can the function `Combine to one commit`:

1. Open TortoiseGit context menu
2. Select `Show Log`
3. Mark the relevant commits in the log view
4. Select `Combine to one commit` from the context menu

[image: Combine commits]

This function automatically executes all necessary single git steps.
Unfortunatly only available for Windows.

Comment: As far as I am aware, this will not work for merge commits.

Comment: Although it's not commented by any others, this even works for commits which are not at the HEAD. For instance, my need was to squash some WIP commits I did with a more sane description before pushing. Worked beautifully. Of course, I still hope I can learn how to do it by commands.

Comment: This is superb! Everything will be done by just couple of mouse clicks and I could merge 200 commits of old repo before archiving! Thanks. Really useful to make branch tree clean and easily review code changes at once.

Comment: You can similarly select n commits and squash them via GUI of GitHub Desktop https://desktop.github.com/

Answer (score 66):

Many answers are based on `git rebase` command, but in my experience it is somewhat complex and advanced for git-beginners.

Let's say you want to squash last 3 commits. Then following are the steps:

- **Note down current commit id**: Use `git log -1 --oneline` and note the commit-id of the present state (just in case you do something wrong with git reset)
- **Go back 3 commits**: Using `git reset --soft HEAD~3` you'll go back 3 commits (and sort of forget that you've had made these three commits earlier)
- **Do a new commit**: Now simply do `git commit -m <NEW_SINGLE_MESSAGE>` which will automatically combine the three commits under your message

In case something goes wrong with git reset, you can again return to the original state by `git reset --soft <ORIGINAL_COMMIT>`

Comment: It's IMPORTANT to use "--soft" in step #2, otherwise you will just revert to a state three commits ago. I think it should be emphasized.

Comment: Also crucial is that you will need --force when you want to push your squashed commit

Comment: if you're EXTRA nervous like me, you can always create a new branch right before you do `git reset --soft HEAD~3` as a backup. This way you have an exact, easy to use replica of where you started. Even after you've force-pushed at the end

Answer (score 65):

Based on [this article](http://makandracards.com/makandra/527-squash-several-git-commits-into-a-single-commit) I found this method easier for my usecase.

My 'dev' branch was ahead of 'origin/dev' by 96 commits (so these commits were not pushed to the remote yet).

I wanted to squash these commits into one before pushing the change. I prefere to reset the branch to the state of 'origin/dev' (this will leave all changes from the 96 commits unstaged) and then commit the changes at once:

```bash
git reset origin/dev
git add --all
git commit -m 'my commit message'
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  Squash down commits from my feature branch, and then I git cherry pick that commit into my master.

Comment: This does not squash previous commits!

Comment: could you elaborate that a bit further @igorGanapolsky ?

Comment: @trudolf This isn't really squashing (picking individual commits to squash).  This is more of committing all of your changes at once.

Comment: yes, hence it squashes all of your commits into one. congratulations!

Comment: For some reason this overwrites existing changes on master that have been pushed to it after I branched off master to create feature branch. Not sure why though. I will try doing it the other way, as mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: As continuation to my comment. When I create a merge branch, then merge feature branch into it, squashing works fine. It requires a little more work, but still less than cherry-picking everything by hand.

Comment: do we need to push forcefully to remote branch. the commits are already present on remote

Answer (score 62):

[Anomies answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189600/562769) is good, but I felt insecure about this so I decided to add a couple of screenshots.

### Step 0: git log

See where you are with `git log`. Most important, find the commit hash of the first commit you *don't* want to squash. So only the :

[image]

### Step 1: git rebase

Execute [`git rebase -i [your hash]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode), in my case:

```
$ git rebase -i 2d23ea524936e612fae1ac63c95b705db44d937d
```

### Step 2: pick / squash what you want

In my case, I want to squash everything on the commit that was first in time. The ordering is from first to last, so exactly the other way as in `git log`. In my case, I want:

[image]

### Step 3: Adjust message(s)

If you have picked only one commit and squashed the rest, you can adjust one commit message:

[image]

That's it. Once you save this (`:wq`), you're done. Have a look at it with `git log`.

Comment: would be nice to see the final result, e.g., `git log`

Comment: @Axalix Did you remove all your lines? That's how you lose your commits.

Answer (score 46):

I think the easiest way to do this is by making a new branch based on master and doing a `merge --squash` of the feature branch.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature_branch_squashed
git merge --squash feature_branch
```

Then you have all of the changes ready to commit.

Comment: This is a nice alternative to achieve a similar end result. I came looking on how to do it using rebase, but I chose this way better. I keep forgetting about the existence of `git merge`

Comment: I was trying to do other solutions, but for w/e reason they weren't working. This one did.

Comment: Thank you man! It helped me. I'm already desperate to fix anything...

Comment: This works like charm. But I think there is one assumption, you need make sure the feature_branch has 0 behind master branch.

Comment: Nice technique to split the operations into a staging branch! One can then diff clean branches more easily.

Comment: Felipe, you can rebase (without -i) onto master then use this :)

Answer (score 44):

### Procedure 1

1) Identify the commit short hash

```
# git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
abcd1234 Update to Fix for issue B
cdababcd Fix issue B
deab3412 Fix issue A
....
```

Here even `git log --oneline` also can be used to get short hash.

2) If you want to squash (merge) last two commit

```
# git rebase -i deab3412
```

3) This opens up a `nano` editor for merging. And it looks like below

```
....
pick cdababcd Fix issue B
pick abcd1234 Update to Fix for issue B
....
```

4) Rename the word `pick` to `squash` which is present before `abcd1234`. After rename it should be like below.

```
....
pick cdababcd Fix issue B
squash abcd1234 Update to Fix for issue B
....
```

5) Now save and close the `nano` editor. Press `ctrl + o` and press `Enter` to save. And then press `ctrl + x` to exit the editor.

6) Then `nano` editor again opens for updating comments, if necessary update it.

7) Now its squashed successfully, you can verify it by checking logs.

```
# git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
1122abcd Fix issue B
deab3412 Fix issue A
....
```

8) Now push to repo. Note to add `+` sign before the branch name. This means forced push.

```
# git push origin +master
```

Note : This is based on using git on `ubuntu` shell. If you are using different os (`Windows` or `Mac`) then above commands are same except editor. You might get different editor.

### Procedure 2

1. First add the required files for commit

```
git add <files>
```

2. Then commit using `--fixup` option and the `OLDCOMMIT` should be on which we need to merge(squash) this commit.

```
git commit --fixup=OLDCOMMIT
```

Now this creates a new commit on top of HEAD with `fixup1 <OLDCOMMIT_MSG>`.

3. Then execute below command to merge(squash) the new commit to the `OLDCOMMIT`.

```
git rebase --interactive --autosquash OLDCOMMIT^
```

Here `^` means the previous commit to `OLDCOMMIT`. This `rebase` command opens interactive window on a editor (vim or nano) on that
we no need to do anything just save and exiting is sufficient. Because the option passed to this will automatically move the latest
commit to next to old commit and change the operation to `fixup` (equivalent to squash). Then rebase continues and finishes.

### Procedure 3

1. If need to add new changes to the last commit means `--amend` can be used with `git-commit`.

```
    # git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
    cdababcd Fix issue B
    deab3412 Fix issue A
    ....
    # git add <files> # New changes
    # git commit --amend
    # git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
    1d4ab2e1 Fix issue B
    deab3412 Fix issue A
    ....
```

Here `--amend` merges the new changes to last commit `cdababcd` and generates new commit ID `1d4ab2e1`

### Conclusion

- Advantage of 1st procedure is to squash multiple commits and to reorder. But this procedure will be difficult if we need to merge a fix to very old commit.
- So the 2nd procedure helps to merge the commit to very old commit easily.
- And the 3rd procedure is useful in a case to squash a new changes to last commit.

Comment: It only updates the last two commits even I reset to a commit Id to the 6th last commit, do not know why

Comment: Even you can rearrange the commit order. It works fine.

Answer (score 43):

To squash the last 10 commits into 1 single commit:

```bash
git reset --soft HEAD~10 && git commit -m "squashed commit"
```

If you also want to update the remote branch with the squashed commit:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: --force is dangerous when multiple people are working on a shared branch as it blindly updates remote with your local copy.
--force-with-lease could have been better as it makes sure that remote has no commits from others since you last fetched it.

Answer (score 40):

If for example, you want to squash the last 3 commits to a single commit in a branch (remote repository) in for example: https://bitbucket.org

What I did is

1. `git reset --soft HEAD~3`
2. `git commit`
3. `git push origin <branch_name> --force`

Comment: Just be careful, Since if you use force then there is no way to retrieve the previous commits since you removed it

Comment: Nice and quick solution, as for me.

Comment: Force is destructive. This is not squashing commits rather removing the last three commits and adding them back as a fourth (now new) commit, essentially rewriting the history which can break the repo for other users until they also force pull. This will also remove any other commits your team has pushed meanwhile.

Answer (score 39):

If you are on a remote branch(called `feature-branch`) cloned from a Golden Repository(`golden_repo_name`), then here's the technique to squash your commits into one:

1. Checkout the golden repo

   ```
   git checkout golden_repo_name
   ```
2. Create a new branch from it(golden repo) as follows

   ```
   git checkout -b dev-branch
   ```
3. Squash merge with your local branch that you have already

   ```
   git merge --squash feature-branch
   ```
4. Commit your changes (this will be the only commit that goes in dev-branch)

   ```
   git commit -m "My feature complete"
   ```
5. Push the branch to your local repository

   ```
   git push origin dev-branch
   ```

Comment: Since I was just squashing ~100 commits (for syncing svn branches via git-svn), this is far faster than interactively rebasing!

Comment: Reading down, I see @Chris's comment, which is what I used to do (rebase --soft...) - too bad that stackoverflow is no longer putting the answer with hundreds of upvotes at the top...

Comment: agree with you @sage, lets hope they might do it sometime in the future

Comment: This is the right way. Rebase approach is good, but should only be used for squash as a last resort solution.

Comment: I'm getting everything up to date

Answer (score 32):

What can be really convenient:
Find the commit hash you want to squash on top of, say `d43e15`.

Now use

```bash
git reset d43e15
git commit -am 'new commit name'
```

Comment: This. Why don't more people use this? It's way faster than rebasing and squashing individual commits.

Comment: @a3y3 maybe the working directory is not clean. one might stash changes first, in that case.

Comment: Because people need to put all logs of each commit into the new one... manually

Comment: That's excellent.

Answer (score 30):

Did anyone mention how easy it is to do on **IntelliJ** IDEA UI:

- Go to `git` window
- Manually select all the commits you want to merge into one.
- Right-click > `Squash Commits` > Edit the squashed commit message
- Click on branch name on left side > Right-click > Push > `Force Push`

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for merge commits

Comment: This works in Android Studio also.

Answer (score 28):

**method 1** if you have many commits

`git rebase -i master`    then press keyboard 'i' to edit

you will see like this:

```
pick etc1
pick etc2
pick etc2
```

replace the word pick with `'f'` and press `esc y :wq`

```
pick etc1 //this commit will the one commit
f etc2
f etc2
```

and press this command

```
git push origin +head
```

**method 2** if you have few commits
you can do this to delete a commit, you need to do same for delete your second commit and so on

```
git reset --soft HEAD^1 // or git reset --soft head~1
git commit --amend //then press `:wq` 
git push -f
```

**method 3** if you already have one commit and you dont want submit another commit more

```
git add files...
git commit --amend  //then press `:wq`
git push origin +head
```

Comment: It should be noted, that this answer assumes you have `vi` set as your default editor in git.

Answer (score 25):

**simple solution:**

`git reset --soft HEAD~5`

`git commit -m "commit message"`

`git push origin branch --force-with-lease`

Comment: nice try, but there is a better way mentioned here with rebase

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried rebase a lot of times, but only your's worked.

Answer (score 22):

This is super-duper kludgy, but in a kind of cool way, so I'll just toss it into the ring:

```bash
GIT_EDITOR='f() { if [ "$(basename $1)" = "git-rebase-todo" ]; then sed -i "2,\$s/pick/squash/" $1; else vim $1; fi }; f' git rebase -i foo~5 foo
```

Translation: provide a new "editor" for git which, if the filename to be edited is `git-rebase-todo` (the interactive rebase prompt) changes all but the first "pick" to "squash", and otherwise spawns vim - so that when you're prompted to edit the squashed commit message, you get vim. (And obviously I was squashing the last five commits on branch foo, but you could change that however you like.)

I'd probably do what [Mark Longair suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-can-i-squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/5190323#5190323), though.

Comment: +1: that's fun and instructive, in that it's wasn't at all obvious to me that you can put anything more complex than the name of a program in the GIT_EDITOR environment variable.

Comment: You could simplify this using `gawk`. `git -c core.editor="gawk -i inplace '{if(NR>1 && \$1==\"pick\"){\$1=\"squash\"} print \$0}'" rebase -i --autosquash HEAD~5`.

Comment: I prefer this command with `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, for I need `autostash`

Answer (score 21):

If you want to squish *every* commit into a single commit (e.g. when releasing a project publicly for the first time), try:

```
git checkout --orphan <new-branch>
git commit
```

Answer (score 20):

Easiest way to do this is using GitHub Desktop. Just select all the commits in your History, right-click and select "Squash x commits":

[image: GitHub Desktop squash]

Comment: yes, this solved the problem. however is not that-pro comparing to commandline answers

Comment: @Siwei doesn’t matter how “pro” it is if it works

Comment: I tried this because the other answers gave me a super long list of commits that were intimidating to deal with (at work we have a LOT of people touching code and feature branches abound). The message I got when attempting to squash was: "Unable to squash. Squashing replays all commits up to the last one required for the squash. A merge commit cannot exist among those commits."

Comment: This should have more votes so it can be more visible on the first page :)

Answer (score 19):

## ⚠️ WARNING: "My last X commits" might be ambiguous.

```
  (MASTER)  
Fleetwood Mac            Fritz
      ║                    ║
  Add Danny  Lindsey     Stevie       
    Kirwan  Buckingham    Nicks                                              
      ║         ╚═══╦══════╝     
Add Christine       ║          
   Perfect      Buckingham
      ║           Nicks            
    LA1974══════════╝                                    
      ║                  
      ║                  
    Bill <══════ YOU ARE EDITING HERE
  Clinton        (CHECKED OUT, CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY)
```

In this very abbreviated history of the [https://github.com/fleetwood-mac/band-history](https://github.com/fleetwood-mac/band-history/about-our-band-starting-1967.md#i-cant-believe-you-actually-clicked-this) repository you have opened a pull request to merge in the the Bill Clinton commit into the original (`MASTER`) Fleetwood Mac commit.

You opened a pull request and on GitHub you see this:

Four commits:

- Add Danny Kirwan
- Add Christine Perfect
- LA1974
- Bill Clinton

Thinking that nobody would ever care to read the full repository history. (There actually is a repository, click the link above!) You decide to squash these commits. So you go and run `git reset --soft HEAD~4 && git commit`. Then you `git push --force` it onto GitHub to clean up your PR.

And what happens? You just made single commit that get from Fritz to Bill Clinton. Because you forgot that yesterday you were working on the Buckingham Nicks version of this project. And `git log` doesn't match what you see on GitHub.

## MORAL OF THE STORY

1. Find the exact files you want to get *to*, and `git checkout` them
2. Find the exact prior commit you want to keep in history, and `git reset --soft` that
3. Make a `git commit` that warps directly from the *from* to the *to*

Comment: This is 100% the easiest way to do this.  If your current HEAD _is_ the correct state you want, then you can skip #1.

Comment: This is the only way I know that allows to rewrite the first commit history.

Answer (score 19):

Simple one-liner that always works, given that you are currently on the branch you want to squash, master is the branch it originated from, and the latest commit contains the commit message and author you wish to use:

```
git reset --soft $(git merge-base HEAD master) && git commit --reuse-message=HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: I have been absolutely livid with frustration about squashing commits and how stupidly complicated it is - just effing use the last message and squash them all to one commit! Why is it that hard????  This one liner does that for me.  Thank you from the bottom of my angry heart.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't care about the commit messages of the in-between commits, you can use

```
git reset --soft <commit-hash-into-which-you-want-to-squash>
git commit -a --amend
```

Answer (score 11):

> How can I squash my last X commits together into one commit using Git?

```
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

The following content will be shown:

```
pick 1bffc15c My earlier commit
pick 474bf0c2 My recent commit

# ...
```

For the commits that you want to squash, replace **pick** with **fixup**, so it becomes:

```
pick 1bffc15c My earlier commit
fixup 474bf0c2 My recent commit

# ...
```

If it's open in vim (default interface within terminal), then press `Esc` on your keyboard, type `:wq` and `Enter` to save the file.

**Verify**: Check `git log`

Answer (score 10):

If you're working with GitLab, you can just click the Squash option in the Merge Request as shown below. The commit message will be the title of the Merge Request.

[image]

Comment: With `GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.8.6-ee` it just randomly took a commit message for the squashed commit...

Answer (score 10):

We were really happy with this answer, it means you don't need to count through commits.

If you have loads of commits on master branch and want to combine them all into one:

- Ensure you're on the master branch and do **git status** to ensure it's all clean
- Copy the commit SHA for the commit BEFORE you started your work
- **git reset ‒soft commitIdSHA**

[ You'll notice that all your changes at this point will be shown in the source control section of your IDE - good to review them to check it's all there]

- **git commit -am "the message you want that will replace all the other commit messages"**
- git push (will complain as you are behind on the commits) so do **git push --force**

That's it!

Answer (score 9):

What about an answer for the question related to a workflow like this?

1. many local commits, *mixed with multiple merges FROM master*,
2. finally a push to remote,
3. PR and merge TO master *by reviewer*.
   (Yes, it would be easier for the developer to `merge --squash` after the PR, but the team thought that would slow down the process.)

I haven't seen a workflow like that on this page. (That may be my eyes.) If I understand `rebase` correctly, multiple merges would require **multiple conflict resolutions**. I do NOT want even to think about that!

So, this seems to work for us.

1. `git pull master`
2. `git checkout -b new-branch`
3. `git checkout -b new-branch-temp`
4. edit and commit a lot locally, merge master regularly
5. `git checkout new-branch`
6. `git merge --squash new-branch-temp`  // puts all changes in stage
7. `git commit 'one message to rule them all'`
8. `git push`
9. Reviewer does PR and merges to master.

Comment: From many opinions I like your approach. It's very convenient and fast

Answer (score 8):

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^
```

where the number of ^'s is X

(in this case, squash the two last commits)

Comment: Better yet, you can replace the duplicate `^`s with `~X` (where `X` is the number of previous commits, as before), like so: `git rebase -i HEAD~2` for the previous two commits.

Answer (score 8):

I was inspired by [Chris Johnsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/16488841) and find a better solution.

If we wanna squash the last 3 commits, and write the new commit message from scratch, this suffices:

```bash
git reset --soft HEAD~3 && git commit
```

If we wanna squash the last many commits, lets say 162 commits, it's very hard to count the rank of the 162th commit, but we can use the commit ID, this suffices:

```bash
git reset --soft ceb5ab28ca && git commit
```

ceb5ab28ca is the commit ID of the 162th commit.

Answer (score 7):

I find a more generic solution is not to specify 'N' commits, but rather the branch/commit-id you want to squash on top of.  This is less error-prone than counting the commits up to a specific commit—just specify the tag directly, or if you really want to count you can specify HEAD~N.

In my workflow, I start a branch, and my first commit on that branch summarizes the goal (i.e. it's usually what I will push as the 'final' message for the feature to the public repository.)  So when I'm done, all I want to do is `git squash master` back to the first message and then I'm ready to push.

I use the alias:

```bash
squash = !EDITOR="\"_() { sed -n 's/^pick //p' \"\\$1\"; sed -i .tmp '2,\\$s/^pick/f/' \"\\$1\"; }; _\"" git rebase -i
```

This will dump the history being squashed before it does so—this gives you a chance to recover by grabbing an old commit ID off the console if you want to revert.  (Solaris users note it uses the GNU sed `-i` option, Mac and Linux users should be fine with this.)

Comment: I tried the alias but I'm not sure if the sed replaces are having any effect. What should they do?

Comment: The first sed just dumps the history to the console.  The second sed replaces all the 'pick' with 'f' (fixup) and rewrites the editor file in-place (the -i option).  So the second one does all the work.

Comment: You are right, counting N-number of specific commits is very error prone.  It has screwed me up several times and wasted hours trying to undo the rebase.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I would like to know if this workflow will hide possible conflicts on the merge. So please consider if you have two branches master and slave. If the slave has a conflict with the master and we use `git squash master` when we are checked out on the slave. what will it happen? will we hide the conflict?

Comment: @Sergio This is a case of rewriting history, so you probably will have conflicts if you squash commits that have already been pushed, and then try to merge/rebase the squashed version back.  (Some trivial cases might get away with it.)

Comment: @Sergio squashing can hide some conflicts if you do rebases instead of merges.  The merge only happens on the final commit, so it's equivalent to merging the squashed version.  But a rebase has to process each commit, so you might have transitory conflicts that are unrolled by a later commit and you'll get a conflict on each as the rebase is processed.  Rebasing the squashed version hides this intermediate history.

Comment: yes I solved with `git push --force-with-lease` when the branch is mine. I don't have to take care about the history :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to other excellent answers, I'd like to add how `git rebase -i` always confuses me with the commit order - older to newer one or vice versa? So this is my workflow:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~[N]` , where N is the number of commits I want to join, *starting from the most recent one*. So `git rebase -i HEAD~5` would mean "squash the last 5 commits into a new one";
2. the editor pops up, showing the list of commits I want to merge. Now they are displayed in *reverse order*: the older commit is on top. Mark as "squash" or "s" all the commits in there *except the first/older one*: it will be used as a starting point. Save and close the editor;
3. the editor pops up again with a default message for the new commit: change it to your needs, save and close. Squash completed!

Sources & additional reads: [#1](https://www.devroom.io/2011/07/05/git-squash-your-latests-commits-into-one/), [#2](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git).

Answer (score 6):

In question it could be ambiguous what is meant by "last".

for example `git log --graph` outputs the following (simplified):

```
* commit H0
|
* merge
|\
| * commit B0
| |
| * commit B1
| | 
* | commit H1
| |
* | commit H2
|/
|
```

Then last commits by time are H0, merge, B0. To squash them you will have to rebase your merged branch on commit H1.

The problem is that H0 contains H1 and H2 (and generally more commits before merge and after branching) while B0 don't. So you have to manage changes from H0, merge, H1, H2, B0 at least.

It's possible to use rebase but in different manner then in others mentioned answers:

`rebase -i HEAD~2`

This will show you choice options (as mentioned in other answers):

```
pick B1
pick B0
pick H0
```

Put squash instead of pick to H0:

```
pick B1
pick B0
s H0
```

After save and exit rebase will apply commits in turn after H1. That means that it will ask you to resolve conflicts again (where HEAD will be H1 at first and then accumulating commits as they are applied).

After rebase will finish you can choose message for squashed H0 and B0:

```
* commit squashed H0 and B0
|
* commit B1
| 
* commit H1
|
* commit H2
|
```

P.S. If you just do some reset to BO:
(for example, using `reset --mixed` that is explained in more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690845/2405850):

```bash
git reset --mixed hash_of_commit_B0
git add .
git commit -m 'some commit message'
```

then you squash into B0 changes of H0, H1, H2 (losing completely commits for changes after branching and before merge.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this bash function to your bash of .zshrc file.

```bash
# Squash last X commits with a Commit message.
# Usage: squash X 'COMMIT_MSG'
# where X= Number of last commits.
# where COMMIT_MSG= New commit msg.
function squash() {
    if [ -z "${1}" -o -z "${2}" ]; then
        echo "Usage: \`squash X COMMIT_MSG\`"
        echo "X= Number of last commits."
        echo "COMMIT_MSG= New commit msg."
        return 1
    fi

    git reset --soft HEAD~"$1"
    git add . && git ci -m "$2" # With 100 emoji
    git push --force
}
```

Then just run

```bash
squash X 'New Commit Message'
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 3):

First I find out the number of commits between my feature branch and current master branch by

```
git checkout master
git rev-list master.. --count
```

Then, I create another branch based out my-feature branch, keep `my-feature` branch untouched.

Lastly, I run

```
git checkout my-feature
git checkout -b my-rebased-feature
git checkout master
git checkout my-rebased-feature
git rebase master
git rebase head^x -i
// fixup/pick/rewrite
git push origin my-rebased-feature -f // force, if my-rebased-feature was ever pushed, otherwise no need for -f flag
// make a PR with clean history, delete both my-feature and my-rebased-feature after merge
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To **avoid** having to resolve any **merge conflicts** when rebasing onto a commit in the same branch, you can use the following command

`git rebase -i <last commit id before your changes start> -s recursive -X ours`

To squash all commits into one, when you are prompted to edit commits to be merged (-i flag), update all but first action from `pick` to `squash` as recommended in other answers too.

Here, we use the merge strategy (-s flag) `recursive` and strategy option (-X) `ours` to make sure that the later commits in the history win any merge conflicts.

**NOTE**: Do not confuse this with `git rebase -s ours` which does something else.

Reference: [git rebase recursive merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt-recursive)

Comment: Couldn't this be avoided by merging the parent branch before rebasing?

Comment: @Jabari - My answer was for situations when rebasing against a previous commit in the same branch.  For example: If you are working on a change and made 10-15 commits locally, but want to clean-up the commit history before pushing to a remote branch.  You can use this command to squash all your commits into one commit and push that to the remote.

Comment: Gotcha!  I should have read the first line better!

Answer (score 3):

Tried all approaches mention here. But finally my issue resolved by following this link.
https://gist.github.com/longtimeago/f7055aa4c3bba8a62197

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout omgpull 
$ git rebase -i upstream/master

 < choose squash for all of your commits, except the first one >
 < Edit the commit message to make sense, and describe all your changes >

$ git push origin omgpull -f
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say `n` is really large. You do not want to deal with each commit. You just want a new branch called `new_feature_branch` that has 1 commit and all your changes of `old_feature_branch`. You can do the following

```bash
git checkout main 

# will contain changes all changes from old_feature_branch 
git checkout -b new_feature_branch 

# get all changes from old_feature_branch and stage them
for f in $(git --no-pager diff --name-only old_feature_branch ) ; do git checkout old_feature_branch -- $f ; done

git commit -m "one commit message"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [GitUp](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp), select the commit you want to merge with its parent and press **S**. You have to do it once for each commit, but it's much more straightforward than coming up with the correct command line incantation. Especially if it's something you only do once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, you might want to use this powershell code.

```
function SquashCommits([int]$count) {
$commitHashes = git log --pretty=format:%h -n $count    

$commands= ( 0..$($count-2) ) |  %{   "sed -i 's/^pick $($commitHashes[$_])/squash $($commitHashes[$_])/' `$file"    }
$st= $commands -join "`n"

$st="func() { 
local file=`$1
$st 
}; func"
$env:GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=$st
try{
        git rebase -i HEAD~$count
    }finally
    {
        Remove-Item Env:\GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
SquashCommits 3
```

Comment: The advantage here is that it can be easily manipulated to do other things such as drop certain commit.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of existing answers for the specific case when the remote is configured to disallow `--force`; assuming the commits are in a branch that you have permissions to delete remotely:

```bash
# 'rewind' to last commit before your commit (use `git log` to identify)
git reset <hash-BEFORE-first-commit-in-feature>

# re-add files (new and modified)
git add <modified-and-new-files> 

# make new single commit with all changes
git commit -m <new-single-commit-message> 

# delete remote branch if you already pushed a PR
git push origin --delete <feature-branch-name>

git push -u origin <feature-branch-name>
```