# How can I safely commit my changes if the teammate has already pushed

Tags: git

I have the following situation. I have worked on some files and didn't commit/push. My teammate has worked on some other files (different from mine) and already committed/pushed his changes.
How can I safely pull his changes, and then commit and push mine? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update from master, then commit.

Comment: Just do it. this is what GIT is designed to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I need to do "git pull", before or after "git add, git commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529206/when-do-i-need-to-do-git-pull-before-or-after-git-add-git-commit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways you could handle this.  You could `commit` your changes and then `pull`.  You could `stash` your changes, `pull`, and then apply your `stash`.  You could `fetch` first, then `commit` and `rebase`.  I personally like doing this a little more explicitly (with a `fetch` followed by `rebase`, instead of a `pull` which [combines](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description) a `fetch` with a `merge`), but that is just personal preference.

1. `git fetch`
2. `git add <files to add>`
3. `git commit -m <commit message>`
4. `git rebase <branch to replay commit onto (i.e. origin/master)>`

The `rebase` step will provide you the opportunity to resolve any conflicts, if the other developer and you were working in the same space.

You should then be able to `push` your changes.

Answer (score 1):

### Pulling and merging

- commit your changes
- pull the other changes
- fix merge conflicts if there are any
- commit

### Stashing

- stash your changes
- pull the commits from the repo
- get back the stash code

### Rebasing

Bill already covered that

### branching

Create a branch where you commit your changes, switch back to the branch you were at and pull: [Move existing, uncommitted work to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommitted-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git)